# dynamic parameter or variable required as INOUT or OUT argument

Tags: stored-procedures, hsqldb

right now iam trying to create some Stored Procedures for a HSQL-DB.

I want to create a new User and return the ID of the new User.

For example i tried it like this to create the Procedure.

```
create procedure test(out param int)
modifies sql data
begin atomic
set param = 1;
end;
```

=> Call it

```
declare param int ;
call test(param);
call param;
```

=> Error

```
dynamic parameter or variable required as INOUT or OUT argument
```

I can´t find the bug -.-

so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you call the procedure:

```
 declare param int;

 call test(param)

 call param
```

It looks the same, but each statement is executed separately!

Comment: when i execute this  => because ';' required before the second call

Comment: Yes, only the first statement must end with ';'. But you must execute the statements separately, one by one.

Comment: It works when I test with HSQLDB 2.2.9 and two earlier versions. After executing CREATE PROCEDURE, first execute `declare param int;`, then `call test(param)` and `call param` separately, one by one.

Comment: i really want to cry -.- its really like i stay in front of a wall and wonder "where is the wall" :/  anyway thanks

Comment: If are you using database manager, each statement *needs* to be called separately.